# How to unit test `viewDidLoad()`

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, uiviewcontroller, xctest

What is everybody's favourite way of injecting dependencies when unit testing `UIViewController.viewDidLoad()` method on iOS?

Given my implementation is:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var service: Service = Service()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        service.load()
    }
}
```

And my test class is something along this:

```
class MyViewController Tests: XCTestCase {

     var vc: MyViewController!
     var serviceMock = ServiceMock()

    override func setUp() {
       super.setUp()
       let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as! MyViewController
       vc.service = serviceMock
    }
}

func testThatServiceIsCalled() {

       XCTAssertTrue(serviceMock.loadCalled)
 }
```

The obvious problem here is that `viewDidLoad()` is called at the moment I instantiate the viewController and the test fails as the mock is not injected properly.

Any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you need to use the storyboard to create the view controller?

Wouldn't this work?

```
func testThatServiceIsCalled() {
  let vc = MyViewController()
  vc.service = serviceMock
  vc.viewDidLoad()

  XCTAssertTrue(serviceMock.loadCalled)
}
```

Comment: Edited your post to actually inject the dependency. Looks like this is it. Thanks! I knew I've done it somehow in the past. I use the storyboard as it is easier to instantiate outlets (my actually viewDidLoad() needs that). But testing of viewDidLoad() method itself is actually better without using storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR You should not unit test UI-related methods like this.

Controllers and Views are not suitable for unit testing for the simple reason that their usually involves operations that get reflected on the screen, and thus are (very) hard to test. Snapshot testing or UI automation tests are a better candidate for these two components of MVC.

A well-written Controller doesn't contain business logic, it delegates the UI stuff to the View, and the business actions to its Model. With this in mind, it's the Model that should be the one that gets to be unit tested.

Now, if you really want to assert that the your service get's called with the proper methods, you could set your VC as root view controller, this should ensure the `loadView` method gets called, which should trigger the `viewDidLoad` one:

```
func testThatServiceIsCalled() {
    let window = UIWindow(frame:  UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window.rootViewController = vc
    XCTAssertTrue(serviceMock.loadCalled)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That service call might or might not be business logic or UI related. However, I can't be the only one who has (and wants to) even my viewcontrollers covered by unit tests :) I strictly follow TDD and need to have a failing test for that service call in viewDidLoad. UI testing is good, but on a different level of my test pyramid.

Comment: @Mirek updated the answer with details on how to test that, if you really want

Comment: @Mirek regarding coverage over controllers, note that this is not valuable information, as controllers can change they way they render the information on screen at any time